# Why is my loop not working to lower the amount of questions Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program where I have to let the user enter their name and solve 10 math problems, I am trying to use a while loop to allow me to limit the number of questions asked. It seems the function that I am using to lower the number of questions asked is not working. The thing is I have to write a function for all of the steps. Here is the code I have so far. All I want help with is the number of questions being reduced using the function I don't want the whole program being solved. Thank You!

> Write a program that will allow a student to enter their name and then
> ask them to solve  10 mathematical equations.  The program should
> display two random numbers that are to  be added, such as:
>
> ```
>   247
> + 129
> ```
>
> The program should allow the student to enter the answer.  The program
> should then  display whether the answer was right or wrong, and
> accumulate the correct values.  After  the 10 questions are asked,
> calculate the average correct.  Then display the student name,  the
> number correct, and the average correct in both decimal and percentage
> format. In addition to any system functions you may use, you might
> consider the following  functions:
>
> - A function that allows the student to enter their name.
> - A function that gets two random numbers, anywhere from 1 to 500.
> - A function that displays the equation and asks the user to enter their answer.
> - A function that checks to see if the answer is right and accumulates the number  right.
> - A function that calculates the results.
> - A function that displays the student name, the number right, and the average right.

```
import random 

#Making a calculator Program
l = 0 
y = 0 
number_right = 0 
amount_questions = 10 
#Function for name

def get_user_name():
  name = input("What is your name? ")
  return name 
get_user_name()
#function for numebers
def random_number():
  l = random.randint(1,500)
  y = random.randint(1,500)
  return l 
  return y 

l = random_number()
y = random_number()

def check_results():
  print(str(l) + "\n" + "+" + '\n' + str(y))
  user_answer = int(input("What is the answer? "))
  if user_answer == (l + y):
    number_right + 1 
    amount_questions - 1
    print("You got it correct!")
  else:
    amount_questions - 1
    print("You got it wrong.")
  return amount_questions
  return number_right 



while amount_questions > 0:
  #print(str(l) + "\n" + "+" + '\n' + str(y))
  
  amount_questions = check_results()
  number_right = check_results()

print(str(amount_questions))
```

Comment: Why are you using a `while` loop at all? The `while` loop is typically used only in situations where the number of iterations required for some operation is unknown *a priori*. If you know exactly how many times you want to repeat some process, then just use a `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

You can't return two values on two different lines:

```
  return amount_questions
  return number_right
```

The second `return` statement is just skipped, since `return` immediately ends the function call.  Your calling code:

```
  amount_questions = check_results()
  number_right = check_results()
```

is calling the function twice, and getting the same `amount_questions` result both times.

Instead do:

```
  return amount_questions, number_right
```

which returns a tuple; the caller then assigns them by making a *single* function call (which returns a tuple) and then destructuring the tuple, like this:

```
  amount_questions, number_right = check_results()
```

This, however, ignores the larger problem that `amount_questions` isn't even defined or decremented in your function -- and there's no reason for `check_results()` to be the thing keeping track of the number of questions in the first place!  Instead you should have `check_results` simply ask the question and return whether or not the user got it right, and call it in a loop that keeps track of the overall counts, something like:

```
import random

def random_number():
    return random.randint(1, 500)


def check_results(x, y):
    print(f"{x} + {y}")
    result = int(input("What is the answer? ")) == x + y
    if result:
        print("You got it correct!")
    else:
        print("You got it wrong.")
    return result


amount_questions = 10
number_right = 0
for _ in range(amount_questions):
    x, y = random_number(), random_number()
    number_right += check_results(x, y)

print(f"Correct answers: {number_right}")
```

```
334 + 90
What is the answer? 424
You got it correct!
105 + 151
What is the answer? 256
You got it correct!
100 + 131
What is the answer? 231
You got it correct!
148 + 204
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
384 + 128
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
324 + 451
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
160 + 82
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
266 + 27
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
146 + 80
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
124 + 404
What is the answer? 0
You got it wrong.
Correct answers: 3
```

Comment: Thank You for your help.  I understand how you did it and it looks a lot more simple than what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze what you have right now:

```
amount_questions = 10
```

You have initialized the amount_questions here to be 10

```
while amount_questions > 0:
```

This means that the function is the loop will perform while you counter is greater than zero.

From your def_check function, after every operation, you are reducing the amount_questions by subtracting 1.

```
amount_questions - 1
```

The issue here is that although you have subtracted 1, you haven't updated the value of the 'amount_questions' variable. So in order to do that you can use one of the following statements:

```
amount_questions = amount_questions - 1
```

OR

```
amount_questions -= 1
```